# How extract csv's and combine to dataframe in python with oauth autentification from gmail?

Tags: python, json, parsing, oauth-2.0

I'm a junior analyst at a small mobile marketing company. I was recently given a difficult task for me: to write a function that extracts csv's from mails for a certain period (and combines them into a dataframe) from one of our work gmail accounts. The previous function received csv using the imaptools library, which requires a password. However, the password must be updated periodically for security reasons and this is inconvenient.

I created an application on my Google account, connected the gmail API, created an Oauth client id and logged in through a report account, received a token. However, I faced big problems with writing the function. This is a piece of code that I wrote. The msg_ids variable returns the correct list of required ids. But what to do next?

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


CLIENT_ID = 'default.com'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'credentials.json'

creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json')

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

results = service.users().messages().list(userId='default.com', q='has:attachment filename:csv').execute()
messages = results.get('messages', [])
msg_ids = [msg['id'] for msg in messages]
```

Chat GPT offers me the following piece of code, but it doesn't work

```
def get_messages(service, start_date, end_date):
    start_datetime = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d').isoformat() + 'Z'
    end_datetime = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d').isoformat() + 'Z'
    query = f'after:{start_datetime} before:{end_datetime}'
    messages = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query).execute()
    return messages.get('messages', [])

def get_attachments(service, message_id):
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id).execute()
    parts = message['payload']['parts']
    attachments = []
    for part in parts:
        if 'filename' in part:
            file_data = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId='me', messageId=message_id, id=part['body']['attachmentId']).execute()
            file_data = file_data['data']
            file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(file_data.encode('UTF-8'))
            filename = part['filename']
            attachments.append((filename, file_data))
    return attachments

def create_dataframe(attachments):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for filename, data in attachments:
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            temp_df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data))
            df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

Note: I expect a function that extracts csvs from gmail for a arbitrary date range and combines them into a dataframe.

Comment: in `get_messages` change line `query = f'has:attachment filename:csv after:{start_datetime} before:{end_datetime}'` to `query = f'after:{start_datetime} before:{end_datetime}'`

Comment: Thanx for help, but still don't work :(